# Bash - Adding value to specific positions in file

Tags: bash, sed

I need to add the value `A 1` to position 10-12 for all lines beginning with `10` regardless of the length of the line. If there are values present in pos 10-12, then they should be overwritten by the value `A 1`.

I tried the following:

```
sed -i 's/.\{9\}/&A 1/' FILE
```

But, this gives me two issues.

1. The value "A 1" is added to all lines, not only for lines starting with 10.
2. The value does not get printed to the line if the length of the line is <12 positions.

Input file:

```
01SAGHSUIGAUGB    
02AWRHGAWRUIGH    
10H    
02DFHAliffh    
10shaofgvasuioghsfag    
02GAQTHEGHQ    
10FGHOHGFRT    
90AIRLGBA
```

Output file:

```
01SAGHSUIGAUGB
02AWRHGAWRUIGH
10H      A 1
02DFHAliffh
10shaofgvA 1ioghsfag
02GAQTHEGHQ
10FGHOHGFA 1
90AIRLGBA
```

Comment: So you like to add blank spaces after `10H` to get `A 1` at correct location?

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct!

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to do with sed since it requires some counting. You can use Perl:

```
perl -lpe 'if(/^10/){ $_ = sprintf("%-12s",$_); s/(.{9}).../$1A 1/;};' input
```

And a bash script version:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$(printf "%-12s" "$line" | sed 's/^\(10.\{7\}\).../\1A 1/')"
done < input
```

*Gives:*

```
01SAGHSUIGAUGB    
02AWRHGAWRUIGH    
10H      A 1
02DFHAliffh    
10shaofgvA 1ioghsfag    
02GAQTHEGHQ    
10FGHOHGFA 1   
90AIRLGBA
```

Comment: would that match a line longer than twelve characters? TOP doesn't specify the maximum length of the line, or what to do with characters after position 12

Comment: Hi, so close but no cigarr. It works perfect in the example I provided. But, the values i'm changing are actually located in pos 575-613 which gives a reg-exp error:     Lookbehind longer than 255 not implemented in regex m/(?<=.{574}).../ at -e line 1.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i 's/\(10.\{0,8\}\)\.\{0,2\}\(.*\)/\1A 1\2/' FILE` nearly works, the only problem being that if the line is less than 10 characters it doesn't pad it.

Result:

```
$ sed 's/\(10.\{0,8\}\)\.\{0,3\}\(.*\)/\1A 1\2/' test.txt 
01SAGHSUIGAUGB    
02AWRHGAWRUIGH    
10H    A 1
02DFHAliffh    
10shaofgvaA 1suioghsfag    
02GAQTHEGHQ    
10FGHOHGFRA 1T    
90AIRLGBA
```

The .{0,8} could also be written .{,8}, matches any sequqnce of characters from 0-8 characters in length, and the brackets are to group the matched patterns, which can then be referenced in the subtitution by the \1 and the \2. If you had more groups you'd reference them with \3 \4 and so on.

As others have pointed out you can pad the lines first to make sure you get the `A 1` on the correct column, but then you'll need to use something other than sed

Comment: you need a start of line anchor. you also need to remove the final `.*` to prevent truncation of the rest of the line.

Comment: Thanks for that. I purposefully truncated the rest of the line because I didn't see the example with > 12 chars. I've ammended my answer.

Comment: This does not add extra space after 10H, so `A 1` is not at correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own solution, with 2 minor modifications.

1. First, add 10 spaces to every line so there is no issue with short lines
2. Only apply your edits to lines starting with "10"

```
sed -e 's/$/xxxxxxxxxx/' -e '/^10/s/.\{9\}/&A 1/' test.txt
```

The `x`'s represent spaces above

Comment: It works fine on my machine. Did you replace the xxxxxxxxxx with 10 spaces? What output do you get?

Comment: I get this `10H` should be `10H      A 1` (Ubuntu 12.04) (6 space between `H` and `A`

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine:

```
awk '/^10/{$0=$0 "          ";q=substr($0,1,9);r=substr($0,13); $0=q "A 1" r} {sub(/ *$/,x);print}' t
01SAGHSUIGAUGB
02AWRHGAWRUIGH
10H      A 1
02DFHAliffh
10shaofgvA 1ioghsfag
02GAQTHEGHQ
10FGHOHGFA 1
90AIRLGBA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^10/ {
   s/^\(.\{9\}\).../\1A 1/
   t
   s/$/        /
   s/^\(.\{9\}\).*/\1A 1/
   }' YourFile
```

change if start with 10, try to change by `A 1` if string is bigger than 12 char, if failed, add enough  space to reach 9 char and add `A 1`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^10/{:a;s/^.{,11}$/& /;ta;s/^(.{9}).../\1A 1/}' file
```

Pad line with spaces if necessary and then replace characters 10-12  with `A 1`.